# Ruby-on-rails web app with mysql and flutter mobile app with firebase

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, firebase, flutter

1. I'm using **Ruby on Rails** with **MySQL** database to develop a web app locally at the moment.
2. I'm also using **Flutter** with **Firebase** to develop a mobile app.

What i want is to get this two applications connected to the same server or database. So, that this two apps can work together instantaneously. Any action that happens in one of this app then it should be reflected in both. Unfortunately I'm not familiar to develop Ruby on Rails apps with Firebase.

How to connect this two apps in real-time?

Like I said, I usually develop Ruby on Rails app with **MySQL** or **SQLite**.
So should I use **Firebase** for my rails app to get this two app connected to the same database? How can this two apps work together in real-time (if so)?

Is there any possibility (because I'm developing my rails app locally with MySQL on **wamp** server) to get data json format from MySQL database into my Flutter mobile app?

Any idea is more than welcome.

Comment: Peter Csala, thank for the suggestion. You know i'm not from an english country, and i'm doing my best to speek english without using any translator.